# MinGW 4.5.2 - Problem with initializing member arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, initializer

Initializer lists should be supported since gcc 4.4 (and I could also use them in other places without problems), yet when I try to compile this with MinGW 4.5.2 I get a "bad array initializer" error. I do compile with -std=c++0x. "points" is just a Vector2D[4].

What am I doing wrong?

```
BoundingBox::BoundingBox(float width, float height, float posX, float posY) :
points{
          Vector2D{posX,posY},
          Vector2D{posX+width, posY},
          Vector2D{posX+width, posY+height},
          Vector2D{posX, posY+height}
    } //error: bad array initializer
{

}
```

Comment: What GCC version are you compiling with? MinGW isn't a compiler.

Comment: g++ 4.5.2 - I know MinGW isn't a compiler, but I thought that was already implied by the fact that I'm talking about C++ - at least I didn't know MinGW had another C++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding parens:

```
points({Vector2D{posX, posY}, ...})
```

instead of

```
points{Vector2D{posX, posY}, ...}
```

I don't have a compiler at hand to check it.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work (it makes no difference at all, actually). It also doesn't appear to work with std::array - strangely enough, it DOES work with std::vector so I guess I'll just assume it's a bug and settle with that for now.

Answer (score 0):

Your code compiles with gcc 4.6.1 (linux).

So if there was a bug it has been fixed.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: @P0W Since switching to a more recent compiler fixes the problem, I think it actually was a valid answer (the switching was implied). Just to be sure, I tested today, and if the Vector2D class has a non-default constructor, g++ 4.5.2 does generate the error "bad array initializer", whereas with g++ 4.6.4, 4.9 and 5.1 the same code compiles fine.